# Typescript integration testing library to be installed on a server and used by a partner

Tags: software-testing

I'd like to find a reverse swagger.

It would allow me to write test suites about the API specification I'm requesting several partners to implement, and a WebUI allows them to run tests against their endpoints (response schema, headers, response time...)

This UI would get an endpoint URL and show quite detailed errors so that the partner can take action.

I'd rather to get something usable in typescript because I have plenty of Zod validators and schemas, and it would be great to reuse them.

I tried Mocha and Jest, but they don't accept parameters + they're designed to be used from the CLI only. They're clearly not designed for that. Chai could be useful though.

I also tried Postman but it has two drawbacks: I cannot use my Zod schemas there (code duplication, possible errors) and the requests would not be sent from my server IP address (so it does not validate all the network configuration stuff)